# Can sound produce electricity?

Tags: energy, electricity, acoustics

Energies of wind and water can produce electricity. But, can sound energy also be used to produce electricity?

Comment: That's what [microphones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone) do.

Comment: Strictly speaking, only moving-coil and piezoelectric microphones generate electricity. Other types require an external power source to produce a signal.

Comment: I gave an overview of this in this answer. In short, the amount of energy attainable per metre squared from a loud is hundreds of times smaller than that available to a solar panel  - http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231085/could-sound-be-considered-a-kind-of-renewable-energy/231089#231089

Answer (score 8):

In principle, sure. That's what microphones are, as ACuriousMind points out. But if you want to power anything substantial, an important issue to overcome is the relatively small amount of energy contained in sound waves.

According to [this website,](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/Lesson-2/Intensity-and-the-Decibel-Scale) the front rows of a rock concert have a sound intensity of $10^{-1}~\text{W m}^{-2}$. So even if you had a square meter of material that was capable of harnessing all of that energy, that tenth of a watt doesn't get you all that far.

Comment: What if we fix such microphone on every buisy long roads(solar panel would be better) or in underground tunnels and roads(with no light.)
Can we get enough energy then.

Comment: Enough energy for what?